# Given any user- how to find out all such tags for which he/she is the top user?

Tags: support, tags, users, data-explorer, search

Each of the tags have top users, an asker and an answerer.

For example, for the [mythology tag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/mythology/topusers), Keshav Srinivashan is the top answerer as well as the top asker.

Similarly, for the [scripture tag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/scripture/topusers), Tezz is the top answerer as well as the top asker.

Now, Tezz is also the top answerer for the [Purana tag](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tags/puranas/topusers) (which i have found out manually).

My query is suppose i want to know all those tags, for which, Tezz is the top user, how to find that out without manual searching?

(Note that here Tezz is just an example which i have used to clarify my question. I want to know the results generally, for any given user, and not only for him)

**Question:** Given any user- how to find out all such tags for which he/she is the top user?

Answer (score 3):

I have edited a query to make it fulfill half of the requirement. By using this query [Tags for which user is top answerer.](http://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/revision/819981/1011718/tags-for-which-user-is-top-answerer) you can get all the tags for which the given user is top answerer.

Answer (score -2):

I created a query for fetching list of top users by tags. Check this out:

https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/817241/given-any-user-how-to-find-out-for-which-all-tags-he-she-is-the-top-user

Comment: I think your query is not showing correct results. Under my id, it shows Advaita and adisesha in which i'm not top user.

Comment: The query is not working @@Thelittle.. so modifications needed..